# Matching DOC and PDF content to string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, search, doc

So my client want to add a feature to their job site whereby a user uploads a PDF or DOC CV/Resume file to a particular job that they are applying for. The system will then create a score whereby it evaluates how appropriate the candidate is for the job that they're applying for. So in the job description, if it says "2 years banking experience", and in the CV/Resume file it says "Barclays Bank - 2 Years", then it adds more to this score for them.

I have advised the client that I do not think that this is the best way to go about things. I feel it would be much better if the job applicant created a profile on the website where they enter this data into the website themselves (similar to LinkedIn) as all data will be appropriately stored.

They are set on the first option and I'm just wondering what the best way of going about this would be? My first thoughts would be to extract the text contents from the document.

Answer (score 0):

What you want cannot be made fully functional, even though data extraction from DOC and PDF files is possible

Although, you can tell you client that the visitor, candidate, can download a Sample CV, fill it, paste it and then upload it; to get particular ratings